# @Controller classes need to be prototype or singleton?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for a web app

The response time is around 250ms and speed is everything with this app

So when it comes to defining the Controller classes I have made then prototype so many can be running at the same time. The app is stateless

I hope to do some performance test soon but wanted to get opinions if making controller classes prototype would improve performance over singleton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your controller methods are not thread-safe it is better to use "singleton" option. As otherwise any a new instance is created for each request.

But actually I don't think you will notice a great difference in performance for a single request as an overhead of new instance creation should be very small.

Comment: thanks, I will stick to prototype until I can perform some test